# Store Vector on a temporary variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an object follow the player in constant movement.

My code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class SeguirObstaculos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private float zpos;

    void Start() {
        zpos = player.position.z;
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.position.z = zpos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the `Z` position of the object to the current `Z` position of the player, you can use the following code:

```
void Update()
{
   transform.position = new Vector3(
      transform.position.x, 
      transform.position.y,
      player.position.z);
}
```

Comment: Or also `var pos = transform.position; pos.z = player.position.z; transform.position = pos;` this has one property access to `transform.position` less ;)